# Insert Selected Data From Multiple table to a single table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql

I have following table structure in SQL Server 2005.

1. AttendanceDetail (`AttenID, Date, EmpID,....`)
2. A_OfficialDetail (`AttenID, OfficeOut, OfficeIn`)
3. A_Personal Detail (`AttenID, OfficeOut, OfficeIn`)
4. A_RecessDetail (`AttenID, OfficeOut, OfficeIn`)
5. Atten_Temp_AttenDetail** (`EmpID, AttenID, Detail, OfficeOut, OfficeIn`)

I need a pure SQL code to insert data into `table 5` from `table 1,2,3,4` such that:

- `AttendanceDetail` has `EmpID=100`, and `Table 2,3,4` match the `AttenID` of `AttendanceDetail` as for `EmpID=100`.

I tried it with a cursor and looping but couldn't get what I wish, it is inserting more records than I wish. Please Help Me. Thanks in Advance

OfficeOut and OfficeIn should be inserted from 3 tables A_OfficialDetail,A_recessdetail and A_PersonalDetail According to AttenID in AttendanceDetail. The main purpose is to insert data of Official Out-in,Recess Out-in and Personal Out-in in on Atten_Temp_AttenDetail Table. The table should actually look like:

```
==================================
UserID  AttenID  Date      Remark   OfficeOut  OficeIN

100      12      7/8/2011  Office   11:00       12:00

100      12      7/8/2011  Office   13:45        14:00
```

The code I tried is

```
Declare @AttenID bigint

Open cur

Fetch Next from cur into @AttenID

while @@fetch_status=0

begin

insert into Atten_Temp_AttenDetail(userID,AttenID,Date,OfficeOut,OfficeIn)
select @AttenID,A.workingDate,OfficeOut,OfficeIn from A_OfficialDetail as O,AttendanceDetail as A where O.AttenID=@AttenID and A.AttenID=@AttenID

insert into Atten_Temp_AttenDetail(userID,AttenID,Date,OfficeOut,OfficeIn)
select @AttenID,A.workingDate,OfficeOut,OfficeIn from A_PersonalDetail as O,AttendanceDetail as A where O.AttenID=@AttenID and A.AttenID=@AttenID


fetch next from cur into @AttenID

end

close cur

Deallocate cur
```

Comment: Whats the sql for the cursor?

Answer (score 1):

This looks like it is really simple really....

```
INSERT INTO Atten_Temp_AttenDetail 
SELECT 
a.EmpID, 
a.AttenID,
'', -- You have no fields for this in the database, may be in AttendanceDetail
b.OfficeOut, -- With the next two, not sure if you want to use A_OfficialDetail or A_Personal Detail
c.OfficeIn
FROM AttendanceDetail a
INNER JOIN A_OfficialDetail b ON a.AttenID = b.AttenID
INNER JOIN [A_Personal Detail] c ON a.AttenID = c.AttenID
INNER JOIN A_RecessDetail d on a.AttenID = d.AttenID
WHERE a.EmpID = 100
```

This what you are after?

Comment: Dear @Matt Please, look at the modified question, it didn't really work

Comment: +1 - Since this answered what op explained first. @playwithtime : For a more accurate answer, you need to make your question more clear.

Answer (score 0):

I would start by making a query, perhaps by using joins, that gives me the result that should be saved.

Then it would merely just be a kind of select into, in order to save the data in Atten_Temp_AttenDetail.

How the SQL and join should be, depends on how the relation between your tables are

Update: If table 2,3,4 are more or less identical, then how about using UNION?